# Entity Framwork 2 одинаковых свойства в таблице. Ругается, что делать?)

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Подскажите что делать для такой таблицы:

```
public class UnitMeasurementModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UnitFamilyModel Family { get; set; }

    public UnitMeasurementModel Lowwer { get; set; }
    public double LowwerCoefficient { get; set; }
    public UnitMeasurementModel Higger { get; set; }
    public double HiggerCoefficient { get; set; }
}
```

Ругается на:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'DataLayer.Models.UnitMeasurementModel' and 'DataLayer.Models.UnitMeasurementModel'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: Ну а сделать то что он просит пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте прочесть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254724/the-principal-end-of-this-association-must-be-explicitly-configured-using-either) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr). Там есть решение аналогичной вашей проблеме.